# Defining states depending on existance of a file/directory

Tags: salt-stack

How is it possible to get something like the following running:

```
{% if not exist('/tmp/dummy/') then %}
dummy:
  file.touch:
    - name: /tmp/dummy/tmp.txt

...
{% endif %}
```

I need it for installing software from a ZIP-file. I want to unzip on the minions, but there I don't want to have any remnants of licence files, which I only need for installation, left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [unless](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/ref/states/requisites.html#unless) for this.

```
dummy:
  file.touch:
    - name: /tmp/dummy/tmp.txt
    - unless: test -d /tmp/dummy/
```

Answer (score 6):

```
{% if 1 == salt['cmd.retcode']('test -f /tmp/woo.test') %}
ack:
  file.touch:
    - name: /tmp/woo.test
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [pure python renderer](http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.py.html) for salt. Here is how it would look like.

```
#!py
import os

def run():
  # defines the hash config
  config = {}

  if (not os.path.isfile("/tmp/dummy")):
    config["dummy"] = { 
      "file.touch": [
        {'name': '/tmp/dummy'},
      ],  
    }    

  return config
```