# How to make salt execution fail if a file exist

Tags: salt-stack

Lets say in below salt call. I want the salt not to execute anymore further if a file exist.

In below example. It should execute run-aerospike-mem_disk-check but once if it detects file exist in check_bad_conf. It shouldn't execute run-aerospike-config and get some RED color in salt as failed. How to achieve it.

Lets say in below salt call. I want the salt not to execute anymore further if a file exist.

In below example. It should execute run-aerospike-mem_disk-check but once if it detects file exist in check_bad_conf. It shouldn't execute run-aerospike-config and get some RED color in salt execution as failed. How to achieve it.

```
run-aerospike-mem_disk-check:
  cmd.wait:
   - name: /var/local/aero_dmcheck.sh
   - watch:
     - file: /var/local/aero_config

check_bad_conf:
   file.exist : /tmp/badconf
     - failhard : yes

run-aerospike-config:
  cmd.wait:
    - name: /var/local/aero_config.pl
    - watch:
      - file: /var/local/aero_config.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it more clear please.
Why you are so badly after "RED"?
You have `disk-check` to be run only if the bad file exists?
If so it must not run `aerospike-config`?
Run **once** no matter if the file still exists?

`cmd.wait` accepts `onlyif` argument in which you can run command to assert file absence/presence/anything (it is exit code-driven).
However you need to know that if `onlyif` is not satisfied the state turns GREEN not RED
There is also `creates` argument that is designed exactly for running the command if the given file exists.
Refer to `cmd` [manual](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.wait)

As you probably want `aerospike-config` to be run only if the `disk-check` was **not** run maybe it is sufficient to use `file.missing` like so:

```
check:
  file.missing:
    - name: /tmp/badconf
run-aerospike-config:
  cmd.wait:
    - name: /var/local/aero_config.pl
    - watch:
      - file: /var/local/aero_config.yml
    - require:
      - file: check
```

Read more about [Salt requisites here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html)
If you want your `run-aerospike-mem_disk-check` script to be run **exactly once**, why don't you use `cmd.script` and add [`stateful` argument](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#stateful-argument) to prohibit further executions?

Answer (score -1):

I actually never really used it but you can use some kind of "if-statement". Check this out:

[Check file exists and create a symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673022/check-file-exists-and-create-a-symlink)

I think in your case `file.present` or `file.absent` would fit.

Hope that helps.

Comment: file.absent will remove if it exist.