# Saltstack waiting for file appearing

Tags: powershell, salt-stack, configurationmanager

Is it possible to do the same thing in Saltsack, but by embedded functionality (without powershell workaround)?

```
installation:
cmd.run:
- name: ./installation_script

wait for installation:
cmd.run:
 - name: powershell -command "Start-Sleep 10"
 - unless: powershell -command "Test-Path @('/path/to/file/to/appear')"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to do. Do you want to run a command only after the installation is complete? Or do you want to run command only if the file exists?

Comment: @alexK This installation creates a file - it is the marker that task is completed. So I want to go ahead only when file exists.

Comment: Then I'm afraid, there's no real way that will not involve running some kind of OS command. Maybe just to make a state more platform-agnostic you could use python states provider as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21859316/1212203)

Comment: Thanks for the link! So many ways to do one thing :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a better way to do this in the current version of salt.  But there was `retry` logic added into states in the next release Nitrogen.

The way I would do this in that release is.

```
installation:
  cmd.run:
    - name: ./installation_script

wait for installation:
  cmd.run:
    - name: Test-Path @('/path/to/file/to/appear')
    - retry:
      - attempts: 15
      - interval: 10
      - until: True
    - shell: powershell
```

And this will continue to run the Test-Path until it exits with a 0 exit code (or whatever the equivalent is in powershell)

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/ref/states/requisites.html#retrying-states

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

NB: While using retry, pay attention to the indent, it has to be 4 spaces from retry key to form a dictionary for salt. Otherwise it will default to 2 attempts with 30s interval. (2017.7.0.)

```
wait_for_file:
  file.exists:
    - name: /path/to/file
    - retry:
        attempts: 15
        interval: 30
```